# Problem publising site to Windows 2008 server

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, publish

I have an Ajax enabled web app created with Visual Studio 2005 - .Net framework 2.0. I publish this to a Windows 2003 server and everything works fine.

I now need to publish to a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.0 on it. Whereas before I used to publish to http:// .... (because the site on the 2003 server was Frontpage server extension enabled} I can't see how to do this in IIS 7.0 so I have published to a share on the server at \servername\websites\nameofwebsite

When I try to run the site I get this:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Web.Extensions assembly is the Asp.Net Ajax 1.0. Have you installed it on the 2008 server or do you have the .dll file located in sites bin folder?

If you can't find the assembly in C:\Windows\assembly (also check the version) you can either [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en) and install it or put the .dll file into the sites bin folder (you should be able to find it on your development computer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't set the server up ... how can I tell if it has been installed? Thanks.

Comment: Look in C:\Windows\assembly you should fine a System.Web.Extensions with the correct version (you probably also will find one with version 3.5.0.0)

Comment: Thanks for that. The Windows 2003 server has the System.Web.Extensions version 1.0.61025.0 and  3.5.0.0 on it. The Windows 2008 server only has the 3.5.0.0 version on it. I don't seem to be able to copy the assembly - how do I copy it over?

Comment: As far as I know you can't copy anything from C:\Windows\assembly, it's probably easiest to download the installer (see my answer for a link).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to publish to an FTP site. It is a much simpler setup and the publishing  procedure from visual studio is the same.

The setup of web-publishing in IIS is just to complicated.

The FTP server can be either IIS or any other FTP server software.